# Bootstrap tabset justified

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

Bootstrap tabset justified="true" aligns bad on small screens. 
Is there a way to make it justified in height and width?

Im using angularjs-ui-bootstrap

[image]

(I hope you understand danish ;-) )

The code is like this:

```
<tabset justified="true">
<tab ng-repeat="tabsoverview in tabsoverview track by $index" heading="{{tabsoverview.title}}" active="tabsoverview.active" disabled="tabsoverview.disabled">
...............
    </tab>
</tabset>
```

Comment: Add some code please of the problem in question .. even better would be if you could re-produce the "problem" in a fiddle :) https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: you could try `white-space: nowrap;`

Comment: Thanks. That worked perfect :)